# Converting XHTML table to LaTeX using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new in XSLT (v1.0) and I can't convert complex XHTML tables to LaTeX using XSLT.

What I mean when I said complex tables, are tables with rows with different number of columns. In other words, `td` with `colspan`.

i.e. (xhtml table)

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="68" colspan="3"> <p>Values</p> </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td valign="top" width="68"> <p>95</p> </td> 
        <td valign="top" width="68"> <p>169</p> <p> </p> </td> 
        <td valign="top" width="68"> <p>180</p> <p> </p> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I'm doing in the XSL file is:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:table[@border='1']">
    <xsl:text>\begin{center}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>\begin{tabular}{</xsl:text>

    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr[1]/*">
        <xsl:text>c</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>}&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:text>\toprule&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr">
        <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
            <xsl:text>\midrule&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
            <xsl:text>\midrule&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:td|xhtml:th">
            <xsl:if test="name() = 'th'">{\bf </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:if test="name() = 'th'">}</xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:text> \\&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:text>\bottomrule&#10;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>\end{tabular}&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>\end{center}&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

But as you can see, this code just works for simple tables, without the colspan attribute. The code loops around the first `tr`, and for each `td`, it writes an "c". So, in the case above, it will only create a one column table.

What I want to do is count the number of `td`, and the number of colspans if it exists, to create a correct table, with 3 columns.

Does anyone knows how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be asked on stackoverflow (which has a very active XSLT tag) It is not a TeX question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easier in XSLT2 but you can use the `(//*)[position() &lt;= n]` idiom in XSLT 1 to iterate n times. I also fixed up your TeX a bit: `\bf` has been deprecated since latex2e released in back in 1993:-)

---

```
<table  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="68" colspan="3"> <p>Values</p> </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td valign="top" width="68"> <p>95</p> </td> 
        <td valign="top" width="68"> <p>169</p> <p> </p> </td> 
        <td valign="top" width="68"> <p>180</p> <p> </p> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:table[@border='1']">
 <xsl:text>\begin{center}&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\begin{tabular}{</xsl:text>

 <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr[1]/*">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@colspan">
    <xsl:for-each select="(//*)[position()&lt;=current()/@colspan]">c</xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>c</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:text>}&#10;</xsl:text>

 <xsl:text>\toprule&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:tr">
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
   <xsl:text>\midrule&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
   <xsl:text>\midrule&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:for-each select="xhtml:td|xhtml:th">
   <xsl:if test="self::xhtml:th">\bfseries </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
    <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"> \\&#10;</xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>

 <xsl:text>\end{tabular}&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>\end{center}</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
 Values  \\
\midrule
\midrule
 95 & 169   & 180   \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```