# Each row span position from current tr to previous tr

Tags: xslt

first time here. I searched a lot on this site and haven't found a similar example to my problem so I take a chance at posting my question.

I have the following html document that I want to convert to XHTML using a XSLT transformation.

The  input :

```
<html>
<head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <td>This</td>
     <td>is</td>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">This is</td>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>This</td>
     <td>is</td>
     <td>a test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">This</td>
     <td>is a</td>
     <td rowspan="2">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>is</td>
     <td>a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

</html>
```

Expected output

```
    This
    is
    a
    test

    This is
    a
    test

    <rowspan previous position></rowspan previous position>
    This
    is
    a test

    This
    is a
    test


    <rowspan previous position></rowspan previous position>
    is
    a 
    <rowspan previous position></rowspan previous position>
```

[similar xsl but it is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554470/converting-xhtml-table-with-rowspan-and-colspan-to-latex):

Comment: Show your desired output and what XSLT you have written?

Comment: Why you want <rowspan previous position></rowspan previous position> as this it is even not valid xhtml